# Java Stream: Sort by one of the non null date fields

Tags: sorting, date, null, java-stream

I have an object that has multiple date fields `date1`, `date2` and `date3`. `date1` is not null where as the other two dates are nullable. I want to sort list of these objects with following rule

1. If `date2` is null, use `date1`, else use `date2`
2. Compare step 1 output with `date3` and sort by descending order.

Below is my bean.

```
class obj {
    private Date date1;
    private Date date2;
    private Date date3;

    obj(Date date1, Date date2, Date date3) {
        this.date1 = date1;
        this.date2 = date2;
        this.date3 = date3;
    }

    public Date getDate1() {
        return date1;
    }

    public void setDate1(Date date1) {
        this.date1 = date1;
    }

    public Date getDate2() {
        return date2;
    }

    public void setDate2(Date date2) {
        this.date2 = date2;
    }

    public Date getDate3() {
        return date3;
    }

    public void setDate3(Date date3) {
        this.date3 = date3;
    }
}
```

And my list to sort will look like

```
List<obj> aList = Arrays.asList(
                new obj(parseDate("1/1/2018"), null, null),
                new obj(parseDate("4/4/2018"), null, parseDate("6/6/2018")),
                new obj(parseDate("7/7/2018"), parseDate("8/8/2018"), null)
        );
```

Currently, I am doing this using stream.

1. Sort objects that has date3 and get max date object
2. Sort objects that has date2 and get max date object
3. If step 2 result is null, sort objects that has date1 and get max date object
4. Compare step 1 and step2/3 output and sort

Is there any better and shorter way of doing it?

Comment: write list  witch you want to get after sorting, please.

Comment: When you want to sort a list of `obj`, you have to compare instances of `obj` with other instances of `obj`. There is no sense in comparing the fields of one `obj` instance. What is the supposed outcome of comparing the date of step one with the date of `date3`? How is it supposed to affect the result of the sort operation?